# How can I safely kill a SID in Oracle and ensure it was not recently re-used?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, concurrency

I have some Oracle jobs that run, each under its own session of course.

I have another job that detects, using some business logic conditions, whether or not that job should be killed or not.

However, my concern was, what if the job finishes just before I kill it, and the SID is re-used by some other session?

Then I might accidentally kill another session? Seems like a concurrency problem of some kind.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

I assume when you say you're killing the session that you're doing something like issuing an

```
alter system kill session 'SID, serial#'
```

command.  So I assume that the job that is determining what jobs to kill is going to get both the SID and the serial# of the runaway job not just the SID.  If that's the case, there should be no issue.  If the SID is re-used, the serial# will be different.  You'd have to reuse the SID often enough to cycle through all the serial# values before the combination of SID and serial# would be reused.  That should take quite a long time.